# Viewmodel binding for Edit View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

Having some trouble with the "GET" part of the Edit View, and can't really find anything online. So far, this is my POST section:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ContactsEditViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Contacts = TheContactContext.tblContacts.Find(viewModel.ID);
            Contacts.Company = viewModel.Company;
            Contacts.Contact = viewModel.Contact;
            Contacts.Contact2 = viewModel.Contact2;
            Contacts.Email1 = viewModel.Email1;
            Contacts.Email2 = viewModel.Email2;
            Contacts.IsSupplier = viewModel.IsSupplier;
            Contacts.Telephone = viewModel.Telephone;
            Contacts.Link = viewModel.Website;
            Contacts.Notes = viewModel.Notes;

            TheContactContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("~/Contacts/Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I've only ever done this using EntityFramework and letting it scaffold everything, so it's the first time using Viewmodels to do it personally.

Any help in whether my POST action is correct, and some guidance on the GET action would be appreciated :)

Comment: You should post your GET code.  What trouble are you having?

Comment: That's the issue, its currently just public actionresult edit () { return view();}

The page renders find, but it shows no data for the database entry, and I'm unsure how to go about the GET action for an edit page

Comment: You need to read-up on the basics.  Check this out, it's really helpful:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're on the right track with `POST`. `GET` is much more simplier:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new ContactsCreateViewModel() { ... your initial settings, may be contained within constructor of view model directly ... });
}
```

The `GET` request requests server to provide empty form, which is filled by user, and filled data are sent back via `POST`, and processed within your provided function.

## EDIT

If you are talking about Edit, then it is similar with one more step:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var data_model = TheContactContext.tblContacts.Get(id); // get model probably from database
    var view_model = new ContactsCreateViewModel() {
        Company = data_model.Company,
        ...
    }; // copy all data into view model

    return View(view_model); // and display view
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, cheers. Had to use .Find(id) instead of .Get but still seems to work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads for a first time it sends GET request and retrieves model with collection of items from Db. After you've updated some of these items your app sends post request (most likely using Ajax) containing json data. You update your database in controller method and now it's time to refresh your page data. Simplest way is to use ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://" + location.host + "/CTRL/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: yourdata,
}).done(function (html) {
   location.reload(); (or other method to update UI)
}).fail(function (err) {
    alert(err.statusText);
});
```

It's for client side. Server side is smth like :

```
    lock (obj)
    {
        try
        {
            update database here...                   
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, ex.Message);                                               
        }                

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "Update completed");                
    }
```